# $Scope doesn't work on subpage

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

this is my controller,

```html
.state('tabs.urunler',{
  url:'/urunler',
  views:{
   'urunler-tab':{
    templateUrl:'pages/urunler.html',
        controller:'MyCtrl'
   }
  }
 })
  .state('tabs.detail',{
    url:'/urunler/:aId',
    views:{
      'urunler-tab' : {
        templateUrl:'pages/urunlerDetail.html',
        controller : 'MyCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

this is POST method.

```html
$http({
          url : apiAddress + 'getUrunler',
          method : 'POST',
          data : {type}
        }).then(function successCallback(response){

            $scope.urunler = response.data;
            console.log($scope.urunler);
        },function errorCallback(response){
          console.log("error");
        });
```

this is my urunDetails.html

```html
<ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler">
                {{urun.title}}
                <div class="list">
                 {{urun.brand}}
                    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                        <img src ="{{urun.picture}}">
                        <h2>{{urun.brand}}</h2>
                        <p>{{urun.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

this is the Urun.html

```html
 <ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler">
                <div class="list">

                    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="changeUrun('Alix Avien')" href="#/tab/urunler/{{urun.title}}">
                        <img src ="{{urun.picture}}">
                        <h2>{{urun.brand}}</h2>
                        <p>{{urun.title}}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                
           </ion-item>
```

The problem is , I can reach {{urun}} in Urun.html, but when I go to subpage of urun.html which is urundetails.html, $scope doesn't work :/. I've looked the response data after reached the urunDetails.html by writing console.log(); Data is coming but I can not see data on the urunDetails.html page. Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you are binding data to the scope variable outside angular scope digest cycle. For this scenario you will have to manually trigger the digest cycle.

There are no. of ways to trigger the digest cycle manually.

I will suggest just use `$timeout(function(){}, 0);` after `$scope.urunler = response.data`. This will basically trigger the digest cycle once more by taking care of any clashes if there is any digest cycle already running.

Comment: ,Thank you for answer. I make the change but it is still not working. I think, I'll change controller of urunDetails.html page and store and share data between controllers by using factory. If there is no other way..

Answer (score 0):

Your two states use the same controller, but each controller instance seems to have its own $scope.

I experimented with this here in this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/qGO3pIDHezym71l7jygU?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('ctrl1', ctrl1);


ctrl1.$inject = ['$scope'];
function ctrl1($scope){
  $scope.test = 'Something';

  $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.test = 'Something else';
  }
}
```

and

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
      <p>
        {{test}}
      </p>
      <button ng-click="change()">Click me!</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
      <p>
        {{test}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The 'change' function only changes the scope variable in the instance where it is called. My best guess is something similar is happening in your case.

You probably want to use some kind of service to provide your controller with the correct data.

Maybe that helps you with your problem, this is just my best guess though. I unfortunately can't really see what you are trying to do with your provided code samples.

Comment: yes you are right, but I am trying to reach data on subpage, when I am on Parent page, I can reach $scope data but after I go to subpage , I cant reach the same $scope variable. So, I can see the data on console.log when I am on subpage but, cant use the data in ng-repeat loop.

Comment: Can you update your question with some code from your controller?